# How to get multiply address from Google's Api coordinates JS

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I created a map on my website. User can add multiple markers. And on the other page I created a call to these markers. Here is a string:

> string
>   '[{"lat":"40.7181193798","lng":"-84.4847297668","label":"A"},{"lat":"40.9530752681","lng":"-83.9779055864","label":"A"}]'

I send request to

> "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + lat +
>   "," + long + "&sensor=true";

and get JSON, but it's work for 1 location, and if and if I have a lot of addresses to send a lot of requests a lot of this is bad for me, I tried

> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.6859141828,-83.7142337114&latlng=53.9134268282,27.5904791583&sensor=true

but it doesn't work. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you like to achieve I'm pretty sure is not possible - you will need to do one call for each address.

Maybe you could switch from GMapsAPI to some other service that allows you the decoding of multiple adresses like:

- http://www.mapdevelopers.com/batch_geocode_tool.php
- open street map

or you could also switch to the **javascript GApi library** using this code:

```js
var locations = [
  [], // your location 1 coordinates
  [], // your location 2 coordinates
  []  // your location 3 coordinates
];


var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  geocodeAddress(locations[i]);
}

function geocodeAddress(location) {
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': location
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        console.log(result)
    }
  });
}
```

Note: **The javascript library is also just making json requests like you have done with your url above!**

Hope this helps `:)`

Comment: but how i understood, if i will use the second solution I also will send one request for one location? TY for answer

Comment: Yes your right. The library is just putting the right URL's together like you have done by hand before. Difference: The libary does it's fetching asynchronous. **And thats a really big advantage!** @ПавелКушнеревич